# Python Sum even numbers and odd number with Node, tail, Empty

Tags: python, linked-list

So I am trying some things with linked lists using Node, tail and empty but I have no clue on how to make a summs_even or summs_odd function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, tail):
        self.IsEmpty = False
        self.Value = value
        self.Tail = tail

    def __str__(self):
        return str(Node)

class Empty:
    def __init__(self):
        self.IsEmpty = True

Empty = Empty()

l = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4, Empty))))

def summ(l):
    if l.IsEmpty:
        return 0
    else:
        return l.Value + summ(l.Tail)
print("Sum: " + str(summ(l)))
```

Comment: Just use something along the lines `l.Tail.Tail` in order to skip two elements. This will, however, need some more checks to ensure that you are not trying to go beyond the end.

Comment: Tail usually means the end of the entire list. Next would be a better name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines

```
def summ_even(l):
    if l.IsEmpty:
        return 0
    elif l.Value%2==1: # check if value is odd
        return summ_even(l.Tail)
    else:
        return return l.Value + summ_even(l.Tail)
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps me further!